# Mac OS x86 Assembly: Why does the initialized memory amount change?

Tags: macos, assembly

I just started learning assembly a week or so ago, and when debugging a program, I came across some strange memory usage. The following code (see end of post) is broken into two files for a reason.

If I compile and run with

```
gcc main.s
./a.out
```

with only code block 1 running (code block 2 commented out), then the program prints "8", meaning that right when my program starts, the Mac OS automatically puts 8 bytes worth of stuff on the stack, then leaves my program to do its thing.

However, if I compile and run with

```
gcc main.s print.s
./a.out
```

With only code block 2 running (code block 1 commented out), then the program prints "16", meaning that Mac OS is initially putting 16 bytes on the stack instead of 8. When this happens, the offsets applied to `rsp` to achieve 16-byte alignment remain the same, meaning that the start of the stack is being offset by 8 bytes whenever an outside function is called.

I also tried putting the `_printNum` function in the same file as `main.s`, but the discrepancy persisted. Another thing I tried was to add another format string and use it later on in the program to see if something to do with the format string was using memory, but it made no difference.

What I think is going on is that Mac OS is pushing the instruction pointer for the next instruction to execute when my program terminates onto the stack, then pushing the old base stack pointer onto the stack, both 32-bit, for a total of 8 bytes. When I include a function call (either local or external to the main file), it seems like the assembler decides to use 64-bit addresses instead of 32-bit addresses, doubling the memory used, and hence the 16 bytes used.

Why is this happening, and if I am wrong, what is Mac OS doing to the stack? Is any of the extra stack used of value to me? Is the computer doing something else instead of switching from 32-bit to 64-bit addressing? Thanks.

main program (main.s):

```
.cstring
    _format: .asciz "%d\n"

.text
.globl _main

_main:
    movq   %rbp, %rax   # Put stack base pointer in rax
    subq   %rsp, %rax   # Subtract stack pointer to get total memory used
    subq   $8, %rsp     # Get 16-byte alignment

    #---------------------------------------------------------
    # code block 1 - prints rax manually
    #---------------------------------------------------------

    movq   %rax, %rsi           # Value to print needs to be in rsi
    lea    _format(%rip), %rdi  # Address of format string goes in rdi
                                # Don't know what the "_format(%rip)" does,
                                # but it works (any info would be handy)
    call   _printf

    #---------------------------------------------------------
    # code block 2 - prints rax via function call
    #---------------------------------------------------------

    call   _printNum    # Prints the value of rax

    #---------------------------------------------------------
    # stack cleanup and return
    #---------------------------------------------------------

    addq   $8, %rsp     # Account for the previous -8 to rsp
    ret                 # end program
```

printing function (print.s):

```
.cstring
    _format: .asciz "%d\n"

.text
.globl _printNum

# assumes 16-byte aligned when called
# prints the value of the rax register
_printNum:
    push   %rbp         # save %rbp - previous stack base
    movq   %rsp, %rbp   # update stack base
    push   %rsi         # save %rsi - register
    push   %rdi         # save %rdi - register

    # print - already 16 byte aligned (rip and three values for 32 bytes)
    movq   %rax, %rsi            # load the value to print
    lea    _format(%rip), %rdi   # load the format string
    call   _printf

    # restore registers
    popq   %rdi
    popq   %rsi
    popq   %rbp

    # return
    ret
```

Comment: There's no reason to assume that RBP has any particular value. The caller can use it for whatever purpose it wants. Notice how your own `_main` function doesn't set RBP, so any function it calls can't determine how much stack `_main` uses by subtracting RSP from RBP either.

Comment: So in _main, RBP is not necessarily the start of the stack? If not, then what is it set to? I feel like it not being the start of the stack is a bit insecure.

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to look at the code that calls _main to determine that.